# calculating pagination offset of specific row/offset

Tags: php, mysql, math

there is a function for showing posts 
(pleas ignore syntax errors  )

```
function get_all_posts ($offset = 0 )
{
  $q =  $db->query("select * from tbl limit 10 offset $offset ");
  $template->load_view('posts' , $q ); 
}
```

now lets say i have function called `get_one_post` with a single post offset and total posts count as argument

```
function get_one_post($requested_post_offset = 0 , $totl_posts_count = 0 )
{

}
```

basically what i want to do in this `get_one_post` is to calculate page offset of requested_post and call `get_all_posts` function , so it show the page that contains that specific post

```
function get_one_post($requested_post_offset = 0 , $totl_posts_count = 0 )
{
   $page_offset = // calculation( $requested_post_offset , $totl_posts_count );
   get_all_posts ($page_offset);

}
```

i can say

```
 get_all_posts ($requested_post_offset );
```

but it shows requested post as first post in the page ... but i wan to be in it's natural place in the pagination not the first one

how should i do the `calculation` part ?

---------------------------------EDIT----------------------------

please note that i know how to create and implement pagination ... that's not the issue here 
my framework pagination system works with offsets instead of page numbers ..
like if per_page is 10 , pagination links would be like

```
page 1  => page.php?offset=0
page 2  => page.php?offset=10
page 3  => page.php?offset=20
```

in this example if the `$requested_post_offset` is 15 then 
THE PAGE OFFSET IS 10 
 and i should get the result of

```
page 2  => page.php?offset=10
```

Comment: Well the first thing you must understand in most pagination implementations is the total number of records in the table.  Do you have an initial query to determine the row count?

Comment: @MikeBrant i get that in the second argument of `get_one_post` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are m posts per page, the post k will be on page `ceil(k/m)`. For example, if you put 25 posts per page, the post 86 will be on page `ceil(86/25) = 4`.

The offset of the post on the page would be `k%m`, where the position of the first is `0` and of the last `m-1`. For example, `86%25 = 11` so the post 86 would be the 12th on the page.

Comment: thanxd , my function works with offset ... i need page offset not page number

Comment: Why do you need page offset?  that has no concept in SQL.  Typically pages numbers would be 1-based.

Comment: By page offset you mean where on the page the post would be, @max? See update.

Comment: my framework pagination  system works with offsets instead of page numbers

Comment: What is page offset? Offset of what from where?

Comment: i've added more info , pleas look at last code block ... that is what i call `page offset` at the end of the links

Comment: So your "page offset" is page number minus 1, times 10? like 0 = 10*(1-1), 10=10*(2-1), 20=10*(3-1), ...

Comment: there is no page number .... all i got is offset of one post and per_page and total count ....the  `page 2  => page.php?offset=10` is what should i get or rather 10 is what should i get after calculation

Comment: So how did you decide you were on page 2? Do you mean you know your post number `k` and want to know the first post number on its page, assuming `m` posts per page? `floor(k/m)*m` For example you have post 18, you have 15 posts per page, the "offset" is floor(18/15)*15 = 15.

Comment: yes i mean i have post number and i want the number of the first post  in its page ... this `floor(k/m)*m` kinda works but not always .. for example if my post offset is 4 and per_page is 2  `(4/2)*2 = 4`
which is wrong ... it should be `2`

Comment: If you have two posts per page, on the first page you have posts 0 and 1, on the second page you have posts 2 and 3, and on the third you have posts 4 and 5. The page that includes post 4 has offset 4. Why should its offset be 2?

Comment: sorry my bad ... the post offset is 1 based ... ((k-1)/m)*m works great ... thanx

Answer (score 0):

Here are some general formulas typically used in pagination:

```
total_pages = ceil(row_count / row_limit_per_page)
page_at_offset = ceil((zero_based_offset + 1) / row_limit_per_page))
zero_based_offset_for_a_given_page = (page_at_offset - 1) * row_limit_per_page
```

Note that here I am treating page numbers as starting with 1.

If your inputs are `zero_based_offset` (the zero-based offset of the row you are interested in) and the `row_limit_per_page` then you simply need to to use the last two equations.  The first equation is typically used for display purposes (when you need to show the total number of pages for navigation or the like).

Comment: thanx .. i need `zero_based_offset_for_page` of given `post_offset` ... ive added more info

Comment: @max I updated my answer.  The equations I gave will get you there, I just didn't explain the inputs for your specific case.